# Finding a value to the left Reverse Vlookup using INDEX and MATCH VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, worksheet-function

I've seen many forum saying that it is possible to find data to the left column, as opposed to `Vlookup` function.

I have a sheet of which I would like to get the value from the left. In other words, I would like to seach for a serial # on the right, say column 3, and get a value on column 1.

What would an alternative to `Vlookup` in VBA? (i.e., reverse vlookup)

I seen several forums with examples using index match, but I cannot understand the syntax. Can someone please provide me with a simple example?

Here is what I was using before and found out that Vlookup cannot search to the left:

```
Sal = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("3491709101",Sheets(PreviousTabName).Range(ThisRAnge), 2, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an Index-Match combination. Something like this should work:

```
Sal = Application.WorksheetFunction.INDEX(Sheets(PreviousTabName).Range(ThisRAnge),Application.WorksheetFunction.MATCH("3491709101",Application.WorksheetFunction.INDEX(Sheets(PreviousTabName).Range(ThisRAnge),0,3),0),1)
```

Alternatively, assuming column 1's reference is stored in variable `1stColumn`, and column 3 in `3rdColumn` then the code should be:

```
Sal = Application.WorksheetFunction.INDEX(1stColumn,Application.WorksheetFunction.MATCH("3491709101",3rdColumn,0))
```

Comment: Hi Thanks! Here is the code: I get an error "Unable to Get the index Property of the Worksheet function class"

The data is located to the left column "B" (or 2) and the serial #'s are located in column "H" (or 8).

Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong? I've been working on this for two days.@Mistella

Comment: If the serial numbers are in Excel as numbers, not text (to input as text, they would have a `'` in front), then you need to get rid of the quotation marks around the number in the `.Match` section. If that's not it, which version of the answer are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to seach *[sic]* for a serial # on the right, say column 3, and get a value on column 1.

Use Application.Match to retrieve the row number. Using Application.Index is sort of overkill since Cells will do just as well.

```
dim n as variant, val as variant

n = application.match("3491709101", Sheets(PreviousTabName).Range("C:C"), 0)

if not iserror(n) then
    val = Sheets(PreviousTabName).Cells(n, "A").Value
    debug.print val
end if
```

Comment: This is Great! That's what I needed. I was just trying to get the row. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the `VLOOKUP` with `Application.Match`, but you need to add an error handler scenario, just in case the `Application.Match` will fail.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub UseMatch()

Dim PreviousTabName As String
Dim SourceSht As Worksheet
Dim ThisRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, MatchRow As Variant
Dim Val

' set the worksheet object where you have the data you are trying to match it with
Set SourceSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") ' <-- modify "Sheet2" to your sheet's name

' set the range where you want to search for a Match
With SourceSht
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row ' find last row in column "C" , you can change to the column you need

    ' set dynamic Range
    Set ThisRange = .Range(.Cells(1, "C"), .Cells(LastRow, "C")) ' change the column to where your data you are trying to compare lies
End With

If Not IsError(Application.Match("3491709101", ThisRange, 0)) Then
    MatchRow = Application.Match("3491709101", ThisRange, 0) ' row of match found
    Val = SourceSht.Range("A" & MatchRow) ' getting the value 2 columns to the left of column "C"
    MsgBox Val
Else
    ' Match error, raise a msgbox
    MsgBox "Unable finding 3491709101 in range " & ThisRange.Address(0, 0, xlA1), vbCritical, "Error"
End If

End Sub
```

---

**Note**: when dealing with Numeric values, you need to make sure they are formatted the same in both places.

For instance, you are looking for `"3491709101"` which is a numeric value converted to String, so if the source data in `ThisRange` is not set-up the same (as String) match will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your comment to @Mistella, I don't think that you need `Vlookup` or `Match`. My understanding is that you want to find the serial number `"3491709101"` in Column 8 and set the value from `Columns(2)` to the Variable `Sal`. If I'm right, then a simple Find is what you need.

```
Dim rng As Range, findVal As Variant, Sal As Variant
Dim PreviousTabname As Worksheet, ThisRange As Range

Set rng = Sheets(PreviousTabname).Range(ThisRange)

    Set findVal = rng.Find(What:="3491709101", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        If findVal Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        Else: Sal = findVal.Offset(, -6).Value

        End If
    MsgBox Sal
```

Comment: `Range(ThisRange)` when `ThisRange As Range` ? a `Range` inside a `Range` , not a String, or directly use a `ThisRange` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado Looking at his Vlookup code, I understood them to be sheet and range variables, I was just using his variables.I normally use the proper worksheet and range in code unless they will be used multiple times within a large macro.

Answer (score 0):

**Index-Match syntax VBA**

```
Dim ReturnValueRange as range, LookupRange as range

Set ReturnValueRange = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").range("$E$1:$E$7")
Set LookupRange = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").range("$G$1:$G$7")

LookUpValue = "findMe"

Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.INDEX(ReturnValueRange,Application.WorksheetFunction.MATCH(LookUpValue, LookupRange, 0))
```

**Index-Match syntax FORMULA**

```
=INDEX(ReturnValueRange,MATCH(LookUpValue, LookupRange, 0))
```

**LEFT VLOOKUP Syntax VBA**

- Return Error in not match

`Result = WorksheetFunction.VLOOKUP(LookUpValue, WorksheetFunction.CHOOSE(Array(1,2), LookupRange, ReturnValueRange), 2, 0))`

**LEFT VLOOKUP Syntax FORMULA**

```
=VLOOKUP(LookUpValue, WorksheetFunction.CHOOSE({1,2}, LookupRange, ReturnValueRange), 2, 0))
```

- the “CHOOSE” function is manipulating the two fields.
- You’re assigning reference “index” numbers to ranges of data –
  assigning the LookupRange to index number 1 and the ReturnValueRange to index number 2
- So, when you type “2” in the VLookup function, you’re actually
  referring to Index number 2 in the CHOOSE function.